# Hiding Drop Down Boxes if Radio Button other than default is Clicked

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, onchange

I swear I'm going to learn more JavaScript...

I have this page (which really an include file in another ASP page, but I copied the correct  HTML and made it so it'd load by itself for my testing purposes):

[FO Samples](http://www.fromnaturewithlove.com/includes/samples-new.asp)

This is how it should show when they first load it.  If they choose one of the other radio buttons, it should HIDE the 2 dropdown boxes. Using this code (something I found from someone else's question on here), its working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeDropdowns(value) {
        if (value == "0") {
            document.getElementById('SAMPLEDROPDOWN').style.display = 'block';
        } 
        else  {
            document.getElementById('SAMPLEDROPDOWN').style.display = 'none';
        }        
    }
</script>
```

But I can't figure out how to make it show them again if they go back to the "I wanna pick my own!" radio. The value of **SAMPGROUP** is the ID from the database of that sample category group.  So it won't necessarily be in numerical order, it might skip #'s (if we delete a category or something). Basically, it should show the dropdowns if SAMPGROUP = 0 and not if its anything else!

I tried changing my code to this (95 being the value of SAMPGROUP for the "Autumm" option), but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeDropdowns(value) {
        if (value == "0") {
            document.getElementById('SAMPLEDROPDOWN').style.display = 'block';
        } else if (value == "95") {
        document.getElementById('SAMPLEDROPDOWN').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else  {
        document.getElementById('SAMPLEDROPDOWN').style.display = 'none';
    }        
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Mahalo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the "value" in your onchange event, thus it's never equal to 0.  Try changing this:

```
<input type="radio" name="SAMPGROUP" value="0" OnChange="Javascript:ChangeDropdowns()" checked />
```

to

```
<input type="radio" name="SAMPGROUP" value="0" OnChange="Javascript:ChangeDropdowns(0)" checked />
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBxRn/).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be passing any value to the parameter "value" on calling the function ChangeDropdowns. Please ensure you pass the value like ChangeDropdowns(0) etc..